# Devops pipeline provide test- and coverage results

Tags: azure-devops, code-coverage, .net-7.0

Having an Azure devops pipeline I'd like to build my project using docker and to provide code coverage results for the devops dashboard. My problem is that even the test- and coverage results are generated successfully, the following steps getting the testresults and providing coverage results are not successful.
These are the pipeline's respective rows:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: Running build and creating testContainer
  inputs:
   script: |
    docker build -f $(dockerfilePath) --target build -t $(imageRepository):$(tag) .
    docker create -ti --name testcontainer $(imageRepository):$(tag)
    docker cp testcontainer:/TestResults/ $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/testResults
    docker cp testcontainer:/TestResults/Coverage/ $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/coverage
    docker rm -fv testcontainer
    ls -la $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/testResults
    ls -la $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/coverage
- stage: Publish
  displayName: Publish test results
  jobs:
  - job: Publish
    displayName: Publish results
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: PublishTestResults@2
      displayName: 'Publish test results'
      inputs:
        testResultsFormat: 'NUnit'
        testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'
        searchFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/testResults'
    - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
      displayName: 'Publish code coverage results'
      inputs:
        summaryFileLocation: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/coverage/coverage.cobertura.xml'
        pathToSources: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
```

The

```
    ls -la $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/testResults
    ls -la $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/coverage
```

are for checking whether the results are there, there are:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 vsts docker 4096 Nov 21 08:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 vsts docker 4096 Nov 21 08:32 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 vsts docker 2659 Nov 21 08:32 Backend.Tests.trx
drwxr-xr-x 2 vsts docker 4096 Nov 21 08:32 Coverage
total 948
drwxr-xr-x 2 vsts docker   4096 Nov 21 08:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 vsts docker   4096 Nov 21 08:32 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 vsts docker 960773 Nov 21 08:32 coverage.cobertura.xml
```

The **PublishTestResults@2** task returns with this:

```
##[warning]No test result files matching '[ '**/*.trx' ]' were found.
Finishing: Publish test results
```

Just after the **PublishCodeCoverageResults@2** task returns with this:

```
Found 0 result(s) matching pattern: /home/vsts/work/1/a/coverage/coverage.cobertura.xml
##[warning]No code coverage results were found to publish.
##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: NoInputFiles
##[error]NoInputFiles
Finishing: Publish code coverage results
```

Can you please tell me, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your YAML sample, the steps to generate code coverage/test result and the Publish test results step are in the different stages.

Since you are using the Microsoft-hosted agents, the Agents used in these two stages are independent. The test result file generated in the first stage cannot be directly accessed by the second stage.

Refer to this doc: [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

> Each time you run a pipeline, you get a fresh virtual machine for each job in the pipeline. The virtual machine is discarded after one job (which means any change that a job makes to the virtual machine file system, such as checking out code, will be unavailable to the next job)

To solve this issue, you need to add the Publish Build Artifacts task in the first stage and then use the Download Build Artifacts task in the Publish test results stage to download all required files.

Refer to this doc: [Artifacts in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/build-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

For example:

```
stages:
- stage: Stage
  jobs:
  - job: 
    steps:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: Running build and creating testContainer
      inputs:
       script: |
        docker build -f $(dockerfilePath) --target build -t $(imageRepository):$(tag) .
        docker create -ti --name testcontainer $(imageRepository):$(tag)
        docker cp testcontainer:/TestResults/ $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/testResults
        docker cp testcontainer:/TestResults/Coverage/ $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/coverage
        docker rm -fv testcontainer
        ls -la $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/testResults
        ls -la $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/coverage
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'

- stage: Publish
  displayName: Publish test results
  jobs:
  - job: Publish
    displayName: Publish results
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        buildType: 'current'
        downloadType: 'single'
        artifactName: 'drop'
        downloadPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    - task: PublishTestResults@2
      displayName: 'Publish test results'
      inputs:
        testResultsFormat: 'NUnit'
        testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'
        searchFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/testResults'
    - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
      displayName: 'Publish code coverage results'
      inputs:
        summaryFileLocation: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/coverage/coverage.cobertura.xml'
        pathToSources: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
```

In this case, the files can be shared between two stages.

Comment: Thanks!
I forgot to mention, I started with a single stage pipeline, but your recommendation is great to save the artifacts. Unlucky me, with these applied to my pipeline I was not successful getting the test and coverage results, so I've recreated the pipeline as a single-stage one, skipping the pushing into ACR step as I don't need this at this point, and now I get the coverage result as needed

Answer (score 0):

As I was unsuccessful creating a multi-stage pipeline, I've recreated a single stage one, which works, this:

```
trigger:
- main

pr:
  - main

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build image
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build an image
      inputs:
        command: build
        repository: DevProject
        dockerfile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/DevProject.Core/Dockerfile'
        buildContext: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
        tags: |
          $(tag)
    - script: |
        docker create --name temp-container DevProject:$(tag)
        docker cp temp-container:/TestResults $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/TestResults
        docker rm temp-container
      displayName: 'Copy Test Results and Coverage'

    # Publish Test Results
    - task: PublishTestResults@2
      displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
      inputs:
        testResultsFormat: 'NUnit'
        testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'
        searchFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/TestResults'

    # Publish Code Coverage Results
    - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
      displayName: 'Publish Code Coverage Results'
      inputs:
        codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
        summaryFileLocation: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/TestResults/Coverage/coverage.cobertura.xml'
```

(I've left out pushing the container to ACR)